# Does iOS mask every App Icon or just the ones on the home screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcasset

According to this, [Apple Documentation on App Icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html), "When iOS displays an app icon on the Home screen of a device, it automatically applies a mask that rounds the corners. Make sure your icon has 90° corners so it looks good after the mask is applied."

Currently, my app icons already have the rounded corners. I'll gladly color in that transparent space so that it has 90° corners, but the documentation doesn't specify whether or not iOS also applies the mask in Spotlight, in the Settings, etc.

I'm assuming it applies masks to every iOS icon in the AppIcons image set. Just looking for confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Masking is applied in Settings and Spotlight as well.  The point of having your icon extend all the way to 90 degree corners is to allow apple to apply system styling and have consistency across the OS.  Icon rounded corners changed slightly between iOS6 and iOS7.  If you had released an app in the store with which you rounded the icons for in iOS6 and then users upgraded to iOS7, your icons might then have white space in the areas between your rounded corners and Apples rounded corners.